# Sum up horizontal drop-downs with text options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that contains staff names and days of month. Each day has a drop-down list with options like "Office", "Vacation", "Remote work" etc. My goal is summing up days for every option

[image: Main table]

I have also another sheet with option names and their numeric values

[image: Options]

The formula I use for AH2: `SUMIF(C2:AG2, Locations!A2, Locations!C2)` works good but only for first 3 dropdows (columns C, D, E). Changing options in columns F:AG won't update corresponding totals

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `MS365` or `Excel 2021`, you can use `XLOOKUP()` to extract the `Increment Value` for each `Location Code` and then multiply it with a `COUNTIF()` function to get the desired output.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `AH2`

```
=XLOOKUP(" "&AH$1&" *"," "&$B$6:$B$8&" ",$C$6:$C$8,,2)*
COUNTIF(C2:AG2,XLOOKUP(" "&AH$1&" *"," "&$B$6:$B$8&" ",$A$6:$A$8,,2))
```

---

In the above formula for `XLOOKUP()` I have used wild card for match mode since as per your screenshots, the `AI1` cell shows only `Remote` while in other sheet it shows as `Remote Work`

---

Also if you use the `LET()` function then we can avoid repeating the ranges in the formula and makes easier to read.

[image]

---

```
=LET(x,$C$6:$C$8,y,$A$6:$A$8,z,$B$6:$B$8,
XLOOKUP(" "&AH$1&" *"," "&z&" ",x,,2)*
COUNTIF(C2:AG2,XLOOKUP(" "&AH$1&" *"," "&z&" ",y,,2)))
```

---

If you are not using `MS365` or `Excel 2021` then you could try using it with `SUMIFS()` + `COUNTIFS()` with `INDEX()` & `MATCH()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `AH2`

```
=SUMIFS($C$6:$C$8,$B$6:$B$8,AH$1&"*")*
COUNTIFS($C2:$AG2,INDEX($A$6:$A$8,MATCH(" "&AH$1&" *"," "&$B$6:$B$8&" ",0)))
```

---

Another alternative using `FILTER()` & `COUNTIFS()`

```
=LET(x,FILTER(HSTACK($A$6:$A$8,$C$6:$C$8),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AH$1,$B$6:$B$8))),
y,COUNTIFS($C2:$AG2,TAKE(x,,1)),
SUM(y*TAKE(x,,-1)))
```

---

[image]

---

Instead of `COUNTIFS()` in the above formula using `BOOLEAN` Logic

```
=LET(x,FILTER(HSTACK($A$6:$A$8,$C$6:$C$8),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AH$1,$B$6:$B$8))),
y,SUM(--($C2:$AG2=TAKE(x,,1))),SUM(y*TAKE(x,,-1)))
```

---

[image]

---

All the formulas approaches shown above needs to be filled down and filled right accordingly, also do change the ranges as per your suit.

---